# PyFMI: During load_fmu() call for FMU 2.0, Python stopped working with exception code 0xc0000005

Tags: python-2.7, fmi, jmodelica

I am using PyFMI as a FMU master for testing my tool which is acts as a FMU 2.0 slave.

When i call load_fmu('fmuFile.fmu', log_level=5) function for loading the fmu, python.exe is crashing .

When i check event viewer it is showing the exception code 0xc0000005.

How to fix this error or how to get more information about this error?

Note: pyFMI works fine, when my tool acts as FMU 1.0 slave. I use the same python for both FMU 1.0 and FMU 2.0

Following is the extract from the event viewer:

*Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56634a05
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000
Faulting process id: 0x3328
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3375493d4b63f
Faulting application path: C:\JModelica.org-SDK-1.12\Python27\python.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: e9932029-a347-11e7-bb26-40b0341357d4*

Comment: Have you verified that the FMU you are you using works as expected? (i.e. tested using the FMUChecker?)

Comment: Can you share the FMU?

Comment: @ChristianWinther, FMUChecker is also crashing during the test. I will recheck the fmu implementation

Comment: @jrhodin sorry mate, i could not share FMU due to the compliance.